# Html.Kendo Grid Edit Cancel issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Html.Kendo Grid in an MVC application and I am facing an issue to do with the grid edit cancel.

I am dynamically changing grid data and when the data has been changed, if an edit is cancelled it is binding to the default data, not the dynamically changed data.

How can I retain dynamically changed data if the grid edit is cancelled? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you press cancel and your original data comes back, it means the data you have dynamically changed were never saved into the grid's datasource.

Comment: How to Save the grid datasource, If I read the grid datasource data, it has changed value only.

Comment: Please post relevant code. I'm not completely sure how you are changing your datasources.

Comment: $('#chSkipFirstReview').click(function () {

    var grid = $("#gridSpecimenDrugTest").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    
    $(data).each(function () {
        
        var isChecked = $('#chSkipFirstReview:checked').val() ? true : false;
        var testType = $("input:radio[name=rdoREntryTypeSCB]:checked").val();
        if (testType == "2" || isChecked == true) {
            this.set("ShowStatus", "Approved");
        }
        else if (testType == "1" && isChecked == false)
        {
            this.set("ShowStatus", "");
        }

    });  
});